# Operator '&' is not defined for string and type object()

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2019

I am having trouble with my expression. There are a lot of answers here, similar to what I am looking for as an answer but for some reason nothing seems to work. I am aware that I am concatenating different types, but I manage to convert everything to a string:

= "**" & "Start Time"                              & strdup (25 , chr (160)) & " : "   & "**"    & Format(Parameters!StartTime.Value  , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")   & "
"
& "**" & "End Time"                                    & strdup (29 , chr (160)) & " : "   & "**"  & Format(Parameters!EndTime.Value    , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "
"
& "**" & "Order Number"        & strdup (14 , chr (160)) & " : "   & "**"  & Parameters!EqId.Value  & "
"
& "**" & "Pack L"      & strdup (14 , chr (160)) & " : "   & "**"  & Parameters!PackLId.Value  & "
"

Did I miss something? thank you!

Comment: The only issue I can think of is one of the parameters are multi-value - making it an Object instead of a String. You could use VBCRLF for a new line.

Comment: Thank you I'll try it!!